# jQuery won't simulate click for mailto link

Tags: jquery

In my jQuery Mobile application, I am trying to click a mailto link programmatically but having no success.

Here is the HTML code:

```
<section id="mensen" data-role="page">

<div data-role="content" class="content">
<a id="emailLink" href="mailto:123@123.com">This is the email link</a>

</div>
</section>
```

The jQuery code is :

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
$('#emailLink').click();
})
```

The link functions normally and the default email client is launched if clicked directly but nothing happens programmatically.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

yes indeed, but this will work

```
$(document).ready(function()
{   
   $('#emailLink')[0].click();
})​
```

edited: ("why?" comment)

because a query done with jquery $(...) returns an array/object of elements.
we have to use the index [0] (expecting only one because its an id) in order to call the .click function of the link object and not on the jquery result array.
<strike>btw i don't expect the array to have that function</strike>

the jquery result array is expected to have a .get(...) function to retrieve elements from the result

Comment: Thanks. Works just fine. Only question is *why*?

Comment: because a query done with jquery $(...) returns an array of elements.

Comment: Hmmm this is interesting as you are actually using the **Javascript** `click()` method rather than jQuery's one. The array indexer `[0]` returns a DOM element rather than a jQuery element. I'm unsure why jQuery's click doesn't fire though, perhaps it doesn't work with URLs but instead fires the click event handler that's bound to that element. Quite interesting.

Comment: indeed because doc's say: "when .click() is called without arguments, it is a shortcut for .trigger("click")"... interested to experiment with $('#emailLink').trigger("click")?

Comment: The only technique that worked for me in Chrome and IE was using pure JavaScript to click the link: document.getElementById('mailto-elem').click();

Answer (score 2):

Bind a click event and trigger the event using window location:

```
<a id='test' href="mailto:test@test.nl">Test</a>​
```

and jquery:

```
$('#test').bind('click', function() {
  window.location.href = $(this).attr('href'); 
});

$('#test').click();
```

​

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/S7wtS/)

Answer (score 0):

After trying all answer and comments on this page, I finally was able to open a mailto link including subject and target properties. I only tested this in Chrome (Version 37.0.2062.124 m) and IE-11:

```
    $("#form-email").on("submit",
        function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var mailto = "aname.gmail"
            $("#email-form").attr("href", "mailto:" + mailto.replace(".", "@") + ".com?subject=Email from someone...");
            document.getElementById('email-form').click();
        }
    );
```

**HTML**

```
    <a href="" id="email-form" target="_blank" >
```